# Excel VBA:How to wrap text in a UserForm command button

Tags: excel, userform

[image: UserForm with unwrapped text]

Hello, the "Add New Subsections" button is actually titled "Add New Subsections Only" so I need to wrap the text.

I've tried googling and not had much luck, right clicking the button in the UserForm edit screen and clicking properties also doesn't do anything.

Comment: Pressing f4 in the VB editor will make sure the properties window is visible. Then select the button and make sure the Word Wrap property is set to True.

Comment: Thanks Rory, turns out somethings up with my window and it only showed after being undocked, I can now access the properties window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select button and set *WordWrap* property (righclick on button -> *Properties*) to `TRUE`:

[image]

Also, this question is more suitable to SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you, was an issue with my VBA window, the properties box would not appear while docked, so had to undock it